# Changing text in 3D text won't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to change the text in my `TextMesh`. However, I've tried many things but it won't change for some reason. The way I do it is:

```
public TextMesh text;
public int count;

void Start () {
    count = 0;
    text= gameObject.AddComponent<TextMesh>();
    text.text = "Counter: " + count.ToString();
}
```

When I run it stays the same. It's the same as the text I wrote in the `Text Mesh` in the editor. I do have 2 3D texts, but I've also tried to `gameObject.Find("CounterText")` but that didn't help either.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `gameObject.GetComponent<TextMesh>();`?

Comment: Yes, but have also tried that.. .:(

Comment: Im sure that I'm missing something here. You have a _public_ variable for the `text`, then reassign it in the Start() function by creating a new text mesh?

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding what you mean but.... Why should I create a new text mesh if I already have one?

Comment: Thats the question I am asking you! The AddComponent function adds a new text mesh to the GameObject!

Comment: It was a suggested solution for somebody else that have a similar problem as me. However, it doesn't work neither does `gameObject.GetComponent<TextMesh>();`

Comment: Did you correctly attach the script?

Comment: Yes, in the editor I clicked on script and could choose a text mesh, where I´'ve chosen my text mesh

Comment: What is the message it shows?

Comment: MissingComponentException: There is no 'TextMesh' attached to the "Can (1)" game object, but a script is trying to access it.

Comment: @Hodhod you code is perfectly valid and can't cause any problem. I have test it . it will add text mesh component in the gameobject and you desired text will be show. attach this script correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MissingComponentException: There is no 'TextMesh' attached to the "Can
>   (1)" game object, but a script is trying to access it.

This simply means that the script in your question is **not** attached to a GameObject that has `TextMesh` component attached to it.

```
gameObject.AddComponent<TextMesh>(); or AddComponent<TextMesh>();
```

will only access the component on the GameObject the script is attached to.

Create a GameObject, select your it, go to **Component** -> **Mesh** -> **Text Mesh**. Modify the **Text Mesh** to what you like.

Do one of the following:

**1**.Attach the script below to that GameObject with the `Text Mesh` component.

```
public TextMesh text;
public int count;

void Start()
{
    count = 0;
    text = gameObject.GetComponent<TextMesh>();
    text.text = "Counter: " + count.ToString();
}
```

**2**.Find the GameObject the `Text Mesh` component is attached to
 then get the `Text Mesh` component from it. You can attach the script below to any GameObject and it will work. Just make sure to change `GameObjectTextMeshIsAttachedTo` to the name of GameObject the `TextMesh` component is attached to.

```
public TextMesh text;
public int count;

void Start()
{
    count = 0;
    text = GameObject.Find("GameObjectTextMeshIsAttachedTo").GetComponent<TextMesh>();
    text.text = "Counter: " + count.ToString();
}
```